# How to fix Ansible error: " conflicting action statements: include, file"

Tags: ansible

I get some error on the include statement. I have two simple playbooks, but cannot find the problem.

files.yml:

```
---
- name: create leading path
  file:
    path: "{{ path }}"
    state: directory
- name: touch the file
  file:
    path: "{{ path + '/' + file }}"
    state: touch
```

include.yml:

```
---
- name: touch files
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - include: files.yaml
      path: /tmp/foo
      file: herp
```

If I run `include.yml` I get this error:

> ERROR! conflicting action statements: include, file
>
> The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/mastering_ansible/touch.yml': line 7, column 13, but may
>   be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
tasks:
          - include: files.yml
            ^ here
```

Comment: `touch.yml` or `files.yml`...are you showing the actual code?

Comment: hi, thanks for arranging the code. Yes, this is actual code.

Answer (score 0):

The module [include](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_module.html#include-include-a-play-or-task-list) is "free-form" only i.e. it has no attributes. The error is the result of the wrong syntax

```
  tasks:
    - include: files.yaml
      path: /tmp/foo
      file: herp
```

Correct

```
  tasks:
    - include: files.yaml
```

If you have trouble with paths see [Search paths in Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#search-paths-in-ansible) and optionally use [Special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables). For example

```
    - include: "{{ playbook_dir }}/tasks/files.yaml"
```

Notes

- *files.yml* is not a playbook.
- The error message is "`/home/ansible/mastering_ansible/touch.yml': line 7, column 13 ...`", but there is no touch.yml among the posted code.
- If the module *include* had attributes *path* and *file* the correct indentation would have been

  ```
  - include: files.yaml
      path: /tmp/foo
      file: herp
  ```
- See [Including and Importing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#including-and-importing) for details.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. I rename it playbook to touch.yml, but it's the same playbook as include.yml. My problem is that i want to make few files in the same dir. In the book they give example with include and then atributes "path" en "file"

Comment: How can i then define the "path"